# Is it normal for project-based employees to not receive a 13th month pay?

Tags: new-job, contracts, bonus, philippines

I've been working for over 5 months now as a project-based junior developer(waiting for regularization). It's my first job, and I'm new to the industry. I don't know much how things work around. Especially with contracts and rights. Now my question is, *is it normal that project-based employees like us to not receive a 13th month pay?* I asked this question because regular employees in our company have already received their pay while us project-based, have not. Another project-based employee like me asked one of our senior if we are included in the pay, but our senior said that he thinks that only regular employees are covered. We haven't asked our HR yet(since it's holiday in our place today), but will probably ask them the day after tomorrow.

In the meantime, I tried searching online about how 13th month pay works and who are covered in it. According to [our government site](http://bwc.dole.gov.ph/faqs-on-13th-month-pay).

> All rank-and-file employees who have worked for at least one (1) month during the calendar year, are entitled to receive 13th month pay regardless of the nature of their employment and irrespective of the methods by which their wages are paid.

I'm wondering if the conditions for 13th month pay depends on the company itself and the place you live in. I felt really disappointed/saddened learning that we(project-based employees) may not receive a 13th month pay.

Comment: All the googling I've done seems to indicate that you'll get paid for it. If HR denies your request, I would be curious to hear their reasoning. PS: I'm not from the Phillippines. I'm no expert. Your question only made me curious about your system. But if I were you, I'd just wait until I could contact HR. Like I said, I think they'll pay it to you.

Comment: I hope they do. But judging the current situation, and base from our senior, it looks like we won’t be getting any. Will update my post once I get to ask our HR.

Comment: I've never heard of 13th month pay. What sort of place does this happen, and are you hiring? :)

Comment: In germany some companies do this. But most companies just slice your normal yearly pay by 13 to get the monthly rate, so Id rather get my wages in 12 month pays than 13. Also around here, it's often that your 13th pay is a fraction of how much months you were in the company the previous year. so starting in december gives you a 1/12 as 13th pay...

Comment: In Finland it is paid as a part of your summer salary. The amount is directly tied to how many vacation days you have accumulated (2 vacation days for each month in your first year on the job), so on your first year of employment you only get a small part of the full amount.

Comment: If, during your hiring you ask a yearly salary number, this becomes a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

Upon speaking with our HR, project-based employees will also receive their 13th month pay. We will just be getting it late compared to regular employees. I'm glad we are also covered in this. It seems that all employees(regardless of the nature of employment) are covered in this bonus, as stated in the link that I attached in my question. Thanks!